# langchain and aws lambda layer in Python

Tags: python, aws-lambda, artificial-intelligence, aws-lambda-layers

I need to create a lambda layer for lambda using python 3.9 to be deployed in aws lambda.

My lambda uses:

- langchain.prompts,
- langchain.retrievers,
- langchain.llms,
- langchain.chains

I was force to pin the architecture and Python version because otherwise, pedantic,  a dependency on langchain won’t work.

So I created requirement.txt for the layer as shown below

```
langchain[all]
```

I run pip install as under so to do not break pydantic:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --platform manylinux1x86_64 --python-version 39 -only-binary=:all:
```

However now I’m getting the following error when invoking the lambda

`Can not import PrompTemplate from langchain.prompts ... Runtime Import Module`

===========SECOND OPTION=====================

As a second option I decided to modify requirements.txt to be like this

```
langchain
langchain.prompts
langchain.retrievers
langchain.llms.bedrock
langchain.chains
```

However now pip install command described above fails with

```
Can not find a version that satisfies the requirement langchain.prompts ( from version:none)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess you uploaded the Lambda layer successfully and added the layer to your function? Did you do everything in the AWS console or used some sort of CDK, SDK, Cloudformation Template, Serverless Framework, SAM for that?

Comment: I used CDK . Do you want me to add the cdk build step

Comment: Did you check in the console that the lambda layer is indeed used by the lambda function? And were you able to test your lambda function locally?